# Add Column to end of CSV file using 'awk' in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, awk

How do you add a column to the end of a CSV file with using a string in a variable?

#### input.csv

```
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,234
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,843
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,472
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,516
```

#### output.csv

```
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,234,2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,843,2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,472,2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhattan,New York,516,2012-02-29 16:13:00
```

#### awk.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F"," '{$6="2012-02-29 16:13:00" OFS $6; print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

My attempt above in **awk.sh** added the string to the end but stripped all the comma separators.

#### awk.sh result

```
2012-02-29 01:00:00 Manhattan New York 234 2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29 01:00:00 Manhattan New York 843 2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29 01:00:00 Manhattan New York 472 2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29 01:00:00 Manhattan New York 516 2012-02-29 16:13:00
```

Appreciate any help!

#### Updated awk.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

GAWK="/bin/gawk"
TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%F %T")
ORIG_FILE="input.csv"
NEW_FILE="output.csv"

#Append 'Create' DateTimeStamp to CSV for MySQL logging
$GAWK -v d="$TIMESTAMP" -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} {$6=d; print}' $ORIG_FILE > $NEW_FILE
rm -f $ORIG_FILE
```

Comment: Isn't it 'ManhattAn' rather than 'ManhattEn'?

Comment: Probably is, I was just quickly typing it for an example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may add a comma to `OFS` (Output Field Separator):

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$6="2012-02-29 16:13:00"; print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Output:

```
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,234,2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,843,2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,472,2012-02-29 16:13:00
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,516,2012-02-29 16:13:00
```

---

**EDIT** to answer the comment of `SirOracle`:

From `awk` man page:

```
       -v var=val
       --assign var=val
              Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such 
              variable values are available to the BEGIN block of an AWK program.
```

So assign your date to a shell variable and use it inside `awk`:

```
mydate=$(date)
awk -v d="$mydate" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$6=d; print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks @Birei. I wasn't sure what OFS was but it makes sense now. Tried your code and it worked.

Comment: Do you know how I can add the date through a variable instead of the hard coded timestamp? I'll add my revised code above to see it better.

Comment: @Birei, I found you code is useful , I have packaged your script and uploaded as #sparrow plugin so that everyone could reuse it - https://sparrowhub.org/info/csv-add-column

Comment: @Birei, nice one thanx. How can anyone include the quotes in the string to be inserted? I wanted to add the string "2.4.0" (**inluding** quotes) in the second column of a `.csv` file, but the code below does not work: `awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$2="\"2.4.0"\"; print}' test.csv > output.csv`

Comment: ...and the following works but removes the last dot from my `2.4.0` string `awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$2="\""2.4.0"\""; print}' test.csv > output.csv`

Comment: @ Can we add header as well. I have data with header. How can i handle this.

Answer (score 18):

I'd do:

```
awk '{ printf("%s,2012-02-29 16:13:00\n", $0); }' input.csv > output.csv
```

This hard codes the value, but so does your code.

Or you can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/,2012-02-29 16:13:00/' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: or: `awk -v date="2012-02-29 16:13:00" -v OFS=, '{print $0, date}'`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the OFS (output field seperator):

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } ; {$6="2012-02-29 16:13:00" OFS $6; print}' input.csv >output.csv
```

which gives me:

```
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,234,2012-02-29 16:13:00,
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,843,2012-02-29 16:13:00,
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,472,2012-02-29 16:13:00,
2012-02-29,01:00:00,Manhatten,New York,516,2012-02-29 16:13:00,
```

Comment: Thanks Jörg Beyer. I removed the OFS $6 using @Birei example below to get rid of the trailing comma. I'm just trying to figure out how to add a variable in place of the hard coded date. I updated the question above with an example.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone wants to create csv file through shell with column names:
where first input stored in variables from_time, to_time.

example:insert two timestamps with from_time and to_time as column names with respective values -

CODE-

```
FROM_TIME=2020-02-06T00:00:00
TO_TIME=2020-02-07T00:00:00
{ echo -e "$FROM_TIME,$TO_TIME";}>input1.csv
{ echo -e "from_time,to_time"; cat input1.csv;} > input.csv
```

first line storing the values
second line responsible for adding column name

Comment: You should edit your answer, it's not clear and it contains errors (second `echo` has a unmatched double quote, for example)